# Circle Summation (30 Points) InterviewStree Puzzle

Tags: puzzle

The following is the problem from [Interviewstreet](http://www.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/)  I am not getting any help from their site, so asking a question here. I am not interested in an algorithm/solution, but I did not understand the  solution given by them as an example for their second input. Can anybody please help me to understand the second Input and Output as specified in the problem statement.

Circle Summation (30 Points)

There are `N` children sitting along a circle, numbered `1,2,...,N` clockwise. The `ith` child has a piece of paper with number `ai` written on it. They play the following game:

In the first round, the child numbered `x` adds to his number the sum of the numbers of his neighbors.

In the second round, the child next in clockwise order adds to his number the sum of the numbers of his neighbors, and so on.

The game ends after `M` rounds have been played.

Input:
The first line contains `T`, the number of test cases. `T` cases follow. The first line for a test case contains two space seperated integers `N` and `M`. The next line contains `N` integers, the `ith` number being `ai`.

Output:
For each test case, output N lines each having N integers. The `jth` integer on the `ith` line contains the number that the jth child ends up with if the game starts with child `i` playing the first round. Output a blank line after each test case except the last one. Since the numbers can be really huge, output them modulo `1000000007`.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 15
3 <= N <= 50
1 <= M <= 10^9
1 <= ai <= 10^9
```

Sample Input:

```
2
5 1
10 20 30 40 50
3 4
1 2 1
```

Sample Output:

```
80 20 30 40 50
10 60 30 40 50
10 20 90 40 50
10 20 30 120 50
10 20 30 40 100



23 7 12
11 21 6
7 13 24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explanation of the second test case. I will use a notation (a, b, c) meaning that child one has number a, child two has number b and child three has number c. In the beginning, the position is always (1,2,1).

If the first child is the first to sum its neighbours, the table goes through the following situations (I will put an asterisk in front of the child that just added its two neighbouring numbers):

(1,2,1)->(*4,2,1)->(4,*7,1)->(4,7,*12)->(*23,7,12)

If the second child is the first to move:

(1,2,1)->(1,*4,1)->(1,4,*6)->(*11,4,6)->(11,*21,6)

And last if the third child is first to move:

(1,2,1)->(1,2,*4)->(*7,2,4)->(7,*13,4)->(7,13,*24)

And as you notice the output to the second case are exactly the three triples computed that way.

Hope that helps.